# Creating WCF Service Reference on remote computer

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, service-reference

I have successfully created hosted WCF Services (using Windows Service Hosting) on both my local dev PC (W7) and also on my production server (Server 2008 R2 Std). I had no problem creating a Service Reference for `localhost` using the Visual Studio 2013 `Add -> Service Reference...` dialog.  But when I went to create the SR for my production server in one of my projects, I would get the error

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://productionserver:4731/CloudNewBundleMutex/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://productionserver:4731/CloudNewBundleMutex/'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://productionserver:4731/CloudNewBundleMutex/.  The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.. If the service is defined in the current
>   solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference
>   again.

*Unless* I also had the WCF service running on my local PC at the same time - then the Service Reference for `productionserver` could be created. ***Even then***, I still had to manually edit `app.config` to point to the production server, as the endpoint address in the file was referencing `localhost` (when it should have been `productionserver`).

So - is this the Expected Behavior? Known bug? Am I creating a remote Service Reference incorrectly?

Comment: How are you hosting the service?

Comment: @Tim sorry for the oversight - updated question to include using Windows Service Hosting.

Comment: Is the Windows Service running on the remote machine?  Also, ensure the bindings on the client and the service match.

Comment: @Tim yes, it is running on the remote machine. I just thought about something: The ``baseAddress`` host name of the ``ServiceHost`` on the remote machine is ``localhost`` - I wonder if the SR creation routines are reading the WSDL and seeing the 'localhost' string and getting confused?

Comment: Hmmm...that might be the case.   You can try changing the base address in the service's config and see if that fixes it, though my gut says that's not the case.

Comment: @Tim that did it! switching the host name in the baseAddress ``Uri`` (2nd param of ``ServiceHost`` ctor) from ``localhost`` to ``productionserver`` fixed the problem.